# I cannot instantiate class using TestNG and IE Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I cannot instantiate the follow class using TestNG and IE Webdriver. Can someone identify what is wrong with my source code?

```
public class NewQATEstClassTest {
    //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        @BeforeMethod
          public void beforeMethod() {
            //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
            String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";
            //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to instantiate the driver after setting the path to IEDriverServer.  Try:

```
public class NewQATEstClassTest {
//For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
        //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
        String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";
        //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      }
```

Comment: Partial fix thus far.....I seeing two windows opening now.

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 11088
Only local connections are allowed
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 49057

Comment: @JJ Do you have more than `@Test` method in this class?  That would cause any method marked as `@BeforeMethod` to be run more than once.  If this is the case, you can change `@BeforeMethod` to `@BeforeClass`.